# How to stop automatic mongodb data cleanup after every deployment of my node.js application to the server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Am new to node.js development and I'm trying to deploy my node.js application in the server in periodic manner like different versions. And am using mongodb for my application.

But the problem is, every time I deploy a new version to the server, my previous database data is getting erased and I need to start the whole process from the scratch.

**.env** File:

```
db_url = 'mongodb://{username}:${encodeURIComponent(password)}@{host}:{port}/{database_Name}'
```

Following is the code for mongodb connection

```
global.__basepath = process.cwd();
global.app = new require("express")();
const http = require('http');

global.express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
global.mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");

dotenv.config();
app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Setup Connection to DB
exports.db = mongoose
    .connect(process.env.db_url,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true})
    .then(() => console.log("Mongo Connection Successfull"))
    .catch(err => console.error(err,"> error occurred from the database"));

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("App is running at http://localhost: %s in %s mode",process.env.PORT,process.env.NODE_ENV);
  console.log("  Press CTRL-C to stop\n");
});
```

Why am I losing all the data and what would be possible reason behind this data loss.
What would be the best way to control this issue and is there any script available to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please add more information to your question. 
Is there something in code that cleans up the data or something specific to your deployment environment?

Comment: No, there is no code like that. I don't know the exact reason behind this issue

Comment: Please see the code of mongo db connection in the question above